# Implementing delegation in decorator pattern

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, decorator

How can I delegate calls to the wrapped object - other than the functionality I changed:

```
class Base {
    doSomething() {}
    doOtherSomething() {}
    doOtherSomething2() {}
}

class Decorator {
   constructor(wrapped) {
      this.wrapped = wrapped;
   }

    doSomething() { 
       console.log("doing more stuff");
       this.wrapped.doSomething()}
    }
}
```

How do I delegate the other functions to automatically be called on the Base class?

Comment: Which kind of decorator? There have been at least three (four?) put forward so far. None has so far made it into the spec.

Comment: Or perhaps you're using "decorator" in a more general sense? Showing us how you intend to use the above would help a lot in terms of making your question clear.

Comment: Side note: Your `class` example is incorrect. You don't use the `function` keyword inside a `class` constructo.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Given the tags, the OP is talking about the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), not the annotation syntax

Comment: @Bergi - Yeah, I figured that too in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're speaking of wrapping things in a general sense (not the various Decorators proposals that have floated around for several years), the easiest way would be to not use a wrapper at all. Instead, either:

1. Use a subclass (if you want to do this for a class of objects), or
2. Replace the method on the original object with your replacement, which calls the original that you replaced (if you want to do it for individual objects).

#2 looks like this:

```
function wrapDoSomething(obj) {
    const original = obj.doSomething;
    obj.doSomething = function(...args) {
        // Do something here, then:
        return original.apply(this, args);
    };
    return obj; // Optional/nice to have
}
```

Live Example:

```js
class Base {
   doSomething() {
       console.log("Original doSomething");
   }
   doOtherSomething() {
       console.log("Original doOtherSomething");
   }
   doOtherSomething2() {}
}

function wrapDoSomething(obj) {
    const original = obj.doSomething;
    obj.doSomething = function(...args) {
        console.log("wrapper doSomething - doing something before");
        const result = original.apply(this, args);
        console.log("wrapper doSomething - doing something after");
        return result;
    };
    return obj;
}

const b = wrapDoSomething(new Base());
b.doSomething();
b.doOtherSomething();
```